# Combine two lists of dataframes, dataframe by dataframe

Tags: r, list, merge, dataframe

Example data:

```
names <- c("Cycling1.opr", "Cycling2.opr", "Cycling3.opr")
mydf1 <- data.frame(V1=c(1:5), V2=c(21:25)) 
mydf2 <- data.frame(V1=c(1:10), V2=c(21:30))
mydf3 <- data.frame(V1=c(1:30), V2=c(21:50))
opr <- list(mydf1,mydf2,mydf3)
mydf4 <- data.frame(timestamp=c(1:5))
mydf5 <- data.frame(timestamp=c(1:10))
mydf6 <- data.frame(timestamp=c(1:30))
timestamp <- list(mydf4,mydf5,mydf6)
names(opr) <- names
names(timestamp) <- names
```

Each list (opr and timestamp) always has the same number of data.frames and when having the same name, each of these data.frames is always the same length. What I would like to do is merge each similarly named dataframe into a single dataframe as part of a final list (perhaps named finalopr) such that its structure is as follows.

```
final_opr <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
      z.surv.mos raceeth year.2cat pt               nevent ncensor nrisk cum.ev cum.cen pointflg pe               se               lower.cl         upper.cl
'38'  36.        1.      1.        0.10896243930756 9.     0.      311.  2474.  1.      1.       0.89103756069243 0.00591553159512 0.09796374785164 0.12119598770184
'134' 36.        1.      2.        0.12919986395988 3.     9.      96.   2469.  958.    1.       0.87080013604011 0.00860912091676 0.11338170396883 0.14722485430136
'183' 36.        2.      1.        0.10763696166101 0.     0.      33.   287.   4.      1.       0.89236303833898 0.01746946721576 0.07830897003442 0.14794876641234
'246' 36.        2.      2.        0.0918969557367  0.     1.      9.    342.   107.    1.       0.90810304426329 0.01975702415208 0.06029765195198 0.1400560419898
'289' 36.        3.      1.        0.14186152615109 2.     0.      72.   440.   12.     1.       0.8581384738489  0.01550071018085 0.11451353670001 0.17574073058836
'366' 36.        3.      2.        0.12701814940611 1.     2.      21.   496.   198.    1.       0.87298185059388 0.01904081251339 0.09468155080317 0.17039866945242
'412' 36.        4.      1.        0.05405405405405 0.     0.      2.    35.    0.      1.       0.94594594594594 0.03717461110299 0.01404207131432 0.20807761862723
'452' 36.        4.      2.        0.09393141727008 0.     1.      2.    40.    13.     1.       0.90606858272991 0.05797150600236 0.02802051731609 0.31488038035974
'491' 36.        5.      1.        0.08880901672474 1.     0.      48.   505.   19.     1.       0.91119098327525 0.01228353765126 0.06772108402588 0.11646360310182
'563' 36.        5.      2.        0.11716939090588 1.     0.      20.   616.   239.    1.       0.88283060909411 0.01608823714602 0.08952365586359 0.15335238527538
")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
> mapply(cbind, opr, timestamp, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
$Cycling1.opr
  V1 V2 timestamp
1  1 21         1
2  2 22         2
3  3 23         3
4  4 24         4
5  5 25         5

$Cycling2.opr
   V1 V2 timestamp
1   1 21         1
2   2 22         2
3   3 23         3
4   4 24         4
5   5 25         5
6   6 26         6
7   7 27         7
8   8 28         8
9   9 29         9
10 10 30        10

$Cycling3.opr
   V1 V2 timestamp
1   1 21         1
2   2 22         2
3   3 23         3
4   4 24         4
5   5 25         5
6   6 26         6
7   7 27         7
8   8 28         8
9   9 29         9
10 10 30        10
11 11 31        11
12 12 32        12
13 13 33        13
14 14 34        14
15 15 35        15
16 16 36        16
17 17 37        17
18 18 38        18
19 19 39        19
20 20 40        20
21 21 41        21
22 22 42        22
23 23 43        23
24 24 44        24
25 25 45        25
26 26 46        26
27 27 47        27
28 28 48        28
29 29 49        29
30 30 50        30
```

Here's the structure:

```
> str(mapply(cbind, opr, timestamp, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
List of 3
 $ Cycling1.opr:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1       : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ V2       : int [1:5] 21 22 23 24 25
  ..$ timestamp: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Cycling2.opr:'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1       : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ V2       : int [1:10] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  ..$ timestamp: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Cycling3.opr:'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1       : int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ V2       : int [1:30] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 ...
  ..$ timestamp: int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: Excellent! Simple as I expected. Thanks :)

Comment: small question: What if dfs in opr and timestamp have different nrows?

Comment: @N.Varela Sounds like you have a new question. Consider posting a new, separate question. You can always link back to this one in your post.